# OpenXML example for filtering pivot table?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I've been tasked with populating an Excel template with data (on sheet 1). The data in that sheet will be used to update 5 or 6 pivot tables on other sheets. That much is working so far with the code below. However, I'm trying to figure out how to remove $0 amounts from the final pivot table result.

```
        public void PivotTableTesting(int recCount)
    {
        PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart ptp =  book.PivotTableCacheDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault();
        PivotTableDefinition def = sheetPart.PivotTableParts.FirstOrDefault().PivotTableDefinition;
        ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.RefreshOnLoad = true;
        ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.RecordCount = UInt32Value.ToUInt32((uint)recCount);
        string val = ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.CacheSource.WorksheetSource.Reference.Value;
        ptp.PivotCacheDefinition.CacheSource.WorksheetSource.Reference = @"A1:AO" + (recCount + 1).ToString();
        ptp.PivotTableCacheRecordsPart.PivotCacheRecords.RemoveAllChildren();
        ptp.PivotTableCacheRecordsPart.PivotCacheRecords.Count = 0;
    }
```

Does anyone have any example code on creating a filter and applying it to a pivot table definition?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same question here, I need to create two Excel, both are almost the same, except one Excel with a Pivot table filter, and another one without

I use Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to reverse engineer the code, for how to install please [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466445/where-can-i-download-open-xml-sdk-2-5-productivity)

Coz the source codes were too long, I listed only the differences below

**For the code with filter**

```
// Generates content of pivotTablePart1.
        private void GeneratePivotTablePart1Content(PivotTablePart pivotTablePart1)
...
            Location location1 = new Location(){ Reference = "A5:B9", FirstHeaderRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataColumn = (UInt32Value)1U, RowPageCount = (UInt32Value)1U, ColumnsPerPage = (UInt32Value)1U };
...

            PivotField pivotField10 = new PivotField(){ Axis = PivotTableAxisValues.AxisPage, ShowAll = false };
...            
            PageFields pageFields1 = new PageFields(){ Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
            PageField pageField1 = new PageField(){ Field = 9, Hierarchy = -1 };
            pageFields1.Append(pageField1);
...
            pivotTableDefinition1.Append(pageFields1);
```

**For the code without filter**

```
// Generates content of pivotTablePart1.
        private void GeneratePivotTablePart1Content(PivotTablePart pivotTablePart1)
...
            Location location1 = new Location(){ Reference = "A5:B9", FirstHeaderRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataColumn = (UInt32Value)1U };
...
            PivotField pivotField10 = new PivotField(){ ShowAll = false };
...
// removed PageFields pageFields1
...
// removed pivotTableDefinition1.Append(pageFields1);
```

I put Pivot on "sheet2", for the field = 9, it refers to the column J (Zero-based index) at "sheet1"
it was defined under GeneratePivotTableCacheDefinitionPart1Content()

```
            WorksheetSource worksheetSource1 = new WorksheetSource(){ Reference = "A1:K7", Sheet = "Sheet1" };
```